# How to the read stored procedure result in Oracle Data Integrator ODI

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-data-integrator

I have a stored procedure in ODI which is directly connected to a pl sql stored procedure inside the database. The stored run correctly. How can I retrieve the value of the output variable "var_esito" once the stored procedure is executed?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgDvZ.jpg)

Comment: If var_esito is the OUT parameter of your stored procedure, it's directly accessible from your PL/SQL block in the ODI procedure. If that's not what your are looking for, you will need to be more precise about what "retrieve the value" means to you. Retrieve where? Which scope?

Comment: That's what I am looking for. How is it directly accessible? I can't figure out how to see the result value

Comment: You can just add a line in your PL/SQL block with any statement that use `var_esito`. For instance `execute immediate 'INSERT INTO my_table (my_column) VALUES (:p1)' using var_esito;`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to use receved value. Anyway you need two tasks in ODI-procedure:

```
Task1--------------------------------------
Target:                      Source:
                             declare
                               var_esito varchar2(100);
                             begin
                               oms_upd_code_stato('','',var_esito);
                               dbms_session.set_context('clientcontext',
                                 'var_esito', var_esito);
                             end;
Task2---------------------------------------
Target:                      Source:
begin                        select sys_context('clientcontext', 'var_esito') VAR_ESITO
/*do smth with #VAR_ESITO*/  from dual  
end;
```

First task calls the procedure and stores value in the session context. The second task gets the value and uses it in other PL/SQL block which is executed on the same or other database.

Value also could be assigned to java variable:

```
Target:
<@
  String var_esito = "#VAR_ESITO";
@>
```

This java variable then could be used anywhere during the session (including ODI-variable assignment) in the following way:

```
<@=var_esito@>
```

**UPDATE for Oracle 12c**

If source database is 12c you may use WITH-clause enhancements and make a function from the procedure, and immediately get a result

```
WITH
  FUNCTION func1(... args ...) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    var_esito varchar2(100);
  BEGIN
    oms_upd_code_stato('','',var_esito); -- your procedure
    RETURN var_esito;
  END;
SELECT func1(....) as VAR_ESITO FROM DUAL;
```

Now again we can use `#VAR_ESITO` or `:VAR_ESITO` in target-code. So, in Oracle 12c ordinary `SELECT` can easily call a stored procedure and return values passed through out-arguments.

Comment: Any way we can put if else statement  in odi procedure with odi tools as technology , if i want to control the execution of odi scenario based upon if else statement how i can do that.<$
if (TRIG_MAP.equals("CASE_2") {
$>
OdiStartScen "-SCEN_NAME=scen1" "-SCEN_VERSION=001"
<$
}
$>
this is what i am trying

Comment: @RajeshKumar, what is this comment about? I beleave you wanted to comment some other topic but posted it here by mistake.